# Android App :Overwriting file instead of appending

Tags: java, android

I am trying to append the notification received in the phone to a text file. But instead of appending its overwriting i.e. only the last notification is stored in the text file. I am also displaying the notifications on the app screen to verify the same.

My MainActivity.java is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TableLayout tab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tab = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("Msg"));
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
                String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
                String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
                 com.example.vk9621.notification1.Filehelper.generateNoteOnSD(getApplicationContext(),"Notification",pack,title,text);
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
                textview.setTextSize(20);
                textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B0719"));
                textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(pack +"<br><b>" + title + " : </b>" + text));
                tr.addView(textview);
                tab.addView(tr);

        }
    };
}
```

My FileHelper.java is :

```
public class Filehelper {

    public static void generateNoteOnSD(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody1,String sBody2, String sBody3) {
        try {
            File gpxfile;
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File file=new File(sFileName);
            if(!file.exists()) {
                gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
            }
            else{
                    gpxfile = file;
                }
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append(sBody1);
            writer.append(sBody2);
            writer.append(sBody3);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My NotificationService.java is :

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }
    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {


        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

        Log.i("Package",pack);
        Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
        Log.i("Title",title);
        Log.i("Text",text);

        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);


    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");

    }
}
```

Can someone tell me whats the error and why all the notifications are not appearing in the text file?

Comment: if file is created and append data to existing file, `FileWriter(File file, boolean true)` second parameter will append the data if it is true.

Answer (score 3):

May be you need to provide append parameter in FileWriter class like this,

FileWriter(File file, boolean append)

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile,true);
```

Call FileWriter constructor like this.

You can checkout this class in detail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)